# SSL certificate: incorrect order

Tags: ssl, certificate, https

I have SSL EV certificate for https://goout.cz. According to this test we are getting A+:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?viaform=on&d=goout.cz

However I get warning for "Incorrect order, Contains Anchor".

But this test: https://cryptoreport.websecurity.symantec.com/checker/views/certCheck.jsp

Says: Certificate not installed correctly.

So far I am unable to find the issue. I thought I might have wrongly concatenated the main and intermediate certificates, but I checked that the main certificate is first and then the intermediate certificates are following.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your file should contain

1. Your certificate
2. The intermediate certificate that signed your certificate
3. Any other intermediate certificates, in order

Your file should NOT contain the root certificate.

In other words:

- Cert 0's subject should be you
- Cert 0's issuer should equal cert 1's subject
- Cert 1's issuer should equal cert 2's subject
- ...
- Cert n's issuer should equal the root's subject
- The root's issuer should by definition be equal to its subject (otherwise it's not a root certificate).

Are you using linux with openssl? If so I can provide a script to check this.

I just connected to your site using

```
$ openssl s_client -showcerts -connect goout.cz:443 2> /dev/null | grep ' [0-9 ] [is]:'
 0 s:/serialNumber=01901613/jurisdictionC=CZ/jurisdictionST=Prague/jurisdictionL=Prague 3/businessCategory=Private Organization/C=CZ/postalCode=130 00/ST=Prague/L=Prague 3/street=Husinecka 792/25/O=GoOut s.r.o./OU=Technical/OU=COMODO EV SSL/CN=goout.cz
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
 1 s:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 2 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
   i:/C=SE/O=AddTrust AB/OU=AddTrust External TTP Network/CN=AddTrust External CA Root
 3 s:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Extended Validation Secure Server CA
   i:/C=GB/ST=Greater Manchester/L=Salford/O=COMODO CA Limited/CN=COMODO RSA Certification Authority
^C
```

It seems you have a file with four certificates, and to get a perfect score you should remove the second one and exchange the last two.

Comment: Thanks for explanation, this makes sense! Do you know why they put the second certificate (which I removed on your suggestion) in the set of Intermediate certificates whereas it should not be there? Anyway, the cryptoreport is now correct, but ssllabs still says incorrect order :/

Comment: I think it was just a cache problem; I just did the ssllabs test on your site and nothing is "incorrect" at all, you have an A+ grade :) As for the root cert in the intermediates . . . no idea!